# Seaborn joint plot with absolute axis label not offset

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I can't figure out how to get the axis labels in my Seaborn Joint plot to not display with absolute values (rather than with an offset). I know I can do this in matplotlib with

```
plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
```

But how do I get it to work with this example

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="white")

# Generate a random correlated bivariate dataset
rs = np.random.RandomState(5)
mean = [0, 0]
cov = [(1, .5), (.5, 1)]
x1, x2 = rs.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, 500).T
x1 = pd.Series(x1, name="$X_1$")
x2 = pd.Series(x2, name="$X_2$")

# Show the joint distribution using kernel density estimation
g = sns.jointplot(x1, x2, kind="kde", size=7, space=0, xlim=(0.995, 1.005))
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreaciated.

Thanks for your suggestion, @ImportanceofbeingErnest; however that still hasn't solved the problem. Here is a screenshot of the plot, I want the x-axis to look like the y-axis in terms of axis labelling. The offsets disappear if I make the x range larger, but for my dataset that doesn't really work.

[image: Current plot. I want the x-axis to not have a offsets]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to add `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` at the beginning of the script <strike>and `plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)` at the end.</strike>

Due to the jointplot creating several axes, `plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)` will only affect the last of them.

An easy solution is to use

```
plt.rcParams['axes.formatter.useoffset'] = False
```

just after the imports. This will turn the offset use off for the complete script.

Comment: @Joe Running your code without the line does not give me any offsets, but the above should work. Some things are really simple. However, if the above answer does not solve your issue, you may need to provide more details, e.g. a screenshot and a more detailed problem description.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, sadly this hasn't helped. I've posted a screenshot of how the plot looks now in the original q.